# Recode continuous data into categorical data using is.na() and if_else() in R

Tags: r, if-statement, na, recode

I have a data frame and one of the columns contain both continuous data and NA. I want to recode all continuous data as one level of categorical data and the NA as another using if_else() and is.na(). How can I do it?

Example data frame:

```
df<-tibble(id=1:10,score=c(3,1,-3,-9,NA,NA,12,NA,5,NA))
```

How can I recode all the numbers into "results" and NA into "no_results"?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, maybe with some data?

Comment: df<-tibble(id=1:10,score=c(3,1,-3,-9,NA,NA,12,NA,5,NA))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided a toy example to stand in for the code that you described:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

Here, we have a data frame with continuous and NA values, and using dplyr, we can use you functions to categorize "x":

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
mutate(new_data = if_else(is.na(x), "is NA", "is not NA"))
```

This creates a new column that categorizes your NA values to "is NA".

Comment: Thank you so much.